# Apps Script to automate Bigquery runs but doesn't do anything

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I'm posting this as a new question as it's slightly different to my original questions on this matter.

I have an apps script to run a query in BigQuery. The script is running and communicating with BigQuery but the job isn't working as expected. I currently get the following error in BigQuery:

> Already Exists: Table fiery-cabinet-111****:***.Test4 (error code: duplicate)

Here is the script:

```
function saveQueryToTable() {
  var projectId = 'fiery-cabinet-*****';
  var datasetId = '11****101';
  var tableId = 'Test4';
  var job = {
    configuration: {
      query: {
        query: 'SELECT * ' +
               'FROM [fiery-cabinet-****:*****.Test2];',
        destinationTable: {
          projectId: projectId,
          datasetId: datasetId,
          tableId: tableId
        }
      }
    }
  };

var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);
  Logger.log(queryResults.status);
}
```

Comment: You need to post the error too! Looking at the code I have an idea what it might be, but can't help until I see the error.

Comment: Hey @GrahamPolley thanks for your comment. I actually don't get an error. I used to get an error before I enabled the APIs which was the following: "Project 603804914871 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. (line 19, file "Code")" but this doesn't happen now that I have the relevant APIs enabled

Comment: there must be something showing in the console or logs...

Comment: @GrahamPolley you are right there is an error happening just saw it in BigQuery. It says: "Already Exists: Table fiery-cabinet-160811:112345101.Test4 (error code: duplicate)" How do I get the code to overwrite the table? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the error first.

Comment: @GrahamPolley done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table you are writing the query results to already exists. You need to set the `WRITE_DISPOSITION` to either:

1. **WRITE_TRUNCATE**: If the table already exists, BigQuery overwrites the table data.
2. **WRITE_APPEND**: If the table already exists, BigQuery appends the data to the table.
3. **WRITE_EMPTY**: If the table already exists and contains data, a 'duplicate' error is returned in the job result.

The default value is WRITE_EMPTY.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query

`configuration.query.writeDisposition`

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to show how it should look in the code itself?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the dataset name from your select query.  Change the query to include the dataset name

```
query: 'SELECT *' +
       'FROM 11****101.Test2;',
```

and verify syntax by viewing the execution transcript and logs

Be aware that providing you have access and the syntax (i.e. project, table and dataset name) correct, your code will just log a table insert job with BigQuery and then finish.

The script completing wont be the same as the BigQuery job completing, for that you'd have to poll the job status.  You could for example be trying to insert to a table that already exists, which would post the job successfully, but fail at execution time (depending on parameters set).

Try the following to obtain the completed query status

```
var queryResults = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(job, projectId);

  var jobId = queryResults.jobReference.jobId;
  var response = 'Running'

  var sleepTimeMs = 500;
  while (response != 'DONE') {
    Utilities.sleep(sleepTimeMs);
    response = BigQuery.Jobs.get(projectId, jobId).status.state;
  }

  Logger.log('Job status : ' + queryResults.status);
```